# How can i set initialize var c#?

Tags: c#

I'm new in c# and have this var:

```
var updates = await Bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);
```

but now want updates define other scope and use it with this shape:

```
updates = await Bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);
```

try define with this code:

```
var updates =(string) null;
```

but in this line c# compiler get this error:

```
    updates = await Bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);
(awaitable)Task<Update[]> TelegramBotClient.GetUpdatesAsync([int offset=0],[int limit=100],[int timeout=0],[CancellationToken cancellationToken=default(CancellationToken)
use this method recieve incoming updates using long polling.
Usage:
Update[] x=await GetUpdateAsync(...);
Can not implicitly convert type 'Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[]' to 'string'
```

How can i solve this code ?thanks:

```
var updates =(string) null;
```

Comment: Of course if you set `var` as `string` it will not convert `Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[]` to `string` and will throw error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `var updates =(string) null;` with `var updates =(Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[]) null;`

Comment: Purpose of implicit typing using `var` keyword - is to make code shorter and more readable. But `var updates =(Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[]) null;` is less readable and longer than explicit typing like `Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[] updates;`, so I wouldn't recommend usage of `var` in such a manner.

Comment: Agree Andy. We can just declare it as Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[] updates;

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, return type of your method is not a `string`, but `Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[]`.

So you can change the code to

```
Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[] updates;
// the rest of code
updates = await Bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);
```

Comment: Thanks for help me my friend